# Error installing pyrebase

Tags: python-3.x

I get this error everytime i install pyrebase on Python 3, I've tried unistalling & reinstalling python and asked mutliple devs but haven't found a fix and was womdering if anyone here can help put this issue to bed.

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

---

> Command
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 -u -c
>   "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/sr/j_54g75x0ql1fn0kkgdffh0m0000gn/T/pip-install-zv7lsnje/pycryptodome/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /private/var/folders/sr/j_54g75x0ql1fn0kkgdffh0m0000gn/T/pip-record-gsrefwhm/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in
>   /private/var/folders/sr/j_54g75x0ql1fn0kkgdffh0m0000gn/T/pip-install-zv7lsnje/pycryptodome/

That is the error preventing it to install

Comment: Have you tried updating pip? With `pip install --upgrade pip`.